# BluetoothManager.frameworkが突然エラー

Tags: xcode

今Xcodeのアップデートを行ったのですが、そのせいかどうかわかりませんが、その後ビルドエラーが発生するようになり困ってます。こんな感じです。
'BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h' file not found
事実Build phase で　Link binary with libraryに移動して
BluetoothManager.frameworkをもう一度追加しようとしても
追加候補に出ません。
これはどうやったら復活できますか？

Answer (score 1):

すみません。解決しました。DUMPして手動でHEADER入れてたのを綺麗さっぱり忘れていました